# How to get the sum of all values?

Tags: google-bigquery

```
select * from
(select * except(rn) from (select sistema_productivo, cod_mpio, periodo, 
has_sembrada,has_sembrada_und, id_cultivo,anio,   row_number() over(partition by cod_mpio order by 
anio desc) rn from TABLENAME where SUBSTR(cod_mpio,1,2) in("23") and sistema_productivo in("ARROZ 
SECANO MANUAL", "MAIZ TECNIFICADO") and periodo in("B"))  t where rn = 1 and anio =(select  max(anio) 
as date_max, from (select * except(rn) from (select sistema_productivo, cod_mpio, periodo, 
has_sembrada,has_sembrada_und, id_cultivo,anio,   row_number() over(partition by cod_mpio order by 
anio desc) rn from TABLENAME where SUBSTR(cod_mpio,1,2) in("23") and sistema_productivo in("ARROZ 
SECANO MANUAL") and periodo in("B"))  t where rn = 1)) 
)
```

This query returned [image]

How Can I to get the total sum of has_sembrada from "MAIZ TECNIFICADO" and "ARROZ SECANO MANUAL"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select sistema_productivo, sum(has_sembrada) as total from
(....)
group by sistema_productivo
```